# How should I persist a matrix type to a sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm using C# and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite version 8.0.2 nuget package in a kestrel app.

As a preface: my table will probably have <100 items in it and updates will be done at user typing speeds. So efficiency is, definitely, not a problem. I just want a datastore that will fit in a file and have ACID guarantees.

I have a Relationship class that has a Frame3D property called Transform. Frame3D is essentially a 4x4 matrix of doubles.

My chosen database doesn't support matrix fields, so I can't simply map my Transform property to a single field.

I can get those doubles as an array of 16 doubles in column major format, and I can construct a matrix from a 16 double array in that format. But now I have to, somehow map those to a row in a table.

I have no experience of using any ORM and I'm trying to weigh up my options.

I'm thinking of three main approaches:

1. raw SQL via ExecuteSqlRawAsync - it seems the least headache
2. add 16 double fields to my Frame3D class - I really don't want to do this
3. use HasConversion to read/write my doubles as a string - yuck! precision?!?
4. using the FluentAPI in my DbContext's OnModelCreating override to do (something?!??).

I suspect that the sensible answer is, "use raw SQL", but has anybody successfully managed to persuade EF to map a single property to multiple fields in a a database row?

From my research (Googling and reading) I have found bits of a solution (though none of it looks elegant). But maybe someone here knows an easy way to do this.

## Some things I have considered

I have looked at shadow properties to create my 16 fields in the database.
I could write some code to write them. I was thinking of overriding my DbContext's SaveChanges

```
public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
{
    var relationships = ChangeTracker.Entries<Relationship>();

    foreach (var entry in relationships)
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            var frame3D = entry.Entity.Transform;
            var components = frame3D.ToColumnMajor();

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                entry.Property($"ColumnMajor{i}").CurrentValue = components[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
}
```

That might cover writing to the database but I haven't worked out how to read from it in a similar fashion (I am still looking).

Has anyone any suggestions? Have I missed the obvious?

## What I Tried

I tried to persist a Frame3D property using EF.

## What I expected

I was expecting this to be easy.

## What actually happened

I fell into a rabbit hole.

Comment: Show your classes. Why do not store matrix in blob field?

Comment: Use Value Conversions. Look at [Collections of primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#collections-of-primitives)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I was thinking of using explicit doubles because they are human readable but then I thought: what human can read 16 doubles and then just know what the frame is? So blob storage is probably the best answer.

Comment: Also you can store it as JSON for human readability. Array of arrays.